# arduino IDE does not find libraries

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide

Upon fresh install of the arduino IDE on Kubuntu 19.10, I downloaded and extracted the MFRC522 library for RFID communication into the `~/sketchbook/libraries/` directory.  No automatic library manager is available in my version of the IDE (2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1), unlike suggested in tutorials on importing libraries.

When I try to compile (click tick mark button) an example file from this library, it aborts compilation with the message:

`DumpInfo.ino:38:21: fatal error: MFRC522.h: file or directory not found` (translated)

The compiler seems to ignore the .h file in the library folder while being aware of the included Example code.  The .h file is at `~/sketchbook/libraries/MFRC522/src/MFRC522.h`, the Example code at `~/sketchbook/libraries/MFRC522/examples/DumpInfo/Dumpinfo.ino`.

I reproduced this problem with another library (Blynk). I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: download the IDE from arduino.cc. the ancient version available over package managers can't work with libraries in 1.5 format

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Juraj, the fault lies with the outdated IDE version shipped with the Ubuntu package sources. Installing from arduino.cc has helped, thanks!